# I have a 3d list of strings and numbers. I need to calculate the sum of each string and then percent in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, percentage

I have a 3d list, of strings and numbers. I need to calculate the sum of each color. Plus, what percentage each item contributes to that total color.

This is what I currently have.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
dc = defaultdict(int) 

l = [('red', 'apple', 7), ('red', 'car', 4), ('red', 'shoe', 3), ('blue', 'candy', 4), ('blue', 'bike', 5), ('green', 'melon', 2)]

for color, name, number in l:
    d[color] += number
    total = str(d)
    
    for color, name, number in l:
        dc[color] /= number
        percent = str(dc)

print(total, percent)
```

What it's printing though is this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'red': 14, 'blue': 9, 'green': 2}) defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'red': 0.0, 'blue': 0.0, 'green': 0.0})
```

The expected output is:

```
red: 14
blue: 9
green: 2

red apple: 7/14 = 50%
red car: 4/14 = 29%
red shoe: 3/14 = 21%
blue candy: 4/9 = 44%
blue bike: 5/9 = 56%`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate one more times on `dc` and use value of `d` base `color_key`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
dc = defaultdict(int) 

l = [('red', 'apple', 0), ('red', 'car', 0), ('red', 'shoe', 0), ('blue', 'candy', 4), ('blue', 'bike', 5), ('green', 'melon', 2)]

for color, name, val in l:
    d[color] += val
    dc[(color, name)] += val
print(d)

dc = {f"{color} {name}" : round(val / d[color], 2) if d[color]!=0 else 'division by zero'  
      for (color, name), val in dc.items()}
      
print(dc)
```

Output:

```
# print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'red': 14, 'blue': 9, 'green': 2})

# print(dc)
{'red apple': 0.5, 'red car': 0.29, 'red shoe': 0.21, 'blue candy': 0.44, 'blue bike': 0.56, 'green melon': 1.0}
```

Comment: Do you know how I could add an if statement to this, to allow me to get pass the divide by 0 error?